# How to WebBrowser post on my facebook wall?

Tags: c#, facebook, post, webbrowser-control

How to WebBrowser post on my wall?

I am using this code, he gets to play text in the textarea but not post.

```
            HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("xhpc_message");
        if (ele != null)
            ele.InnerText = "Hello Word";



        ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Post");
        if (ele != null)
            ele.InvokeMember("click");
```

Do I need to spend some more parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming that the field, "xhpc_message" is where you want to post your message:

```
    Dim inp As HtmlElement
    For Each inp In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
    If inp.GetAttribute("name") = "xhpc_message" Then
    inp.SetAttribute("value", "your text")
    End If
    Next
```

You will then need to figure out what the name of the submit button is to post the form.

Comment: What is the rationale for .xhpc_message? I cannot find this element on the Chrome/Firefox Inspector, but it unexpectedly works.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlElement timelineContainer = null;
```

...

```
timelineContainer = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("timeline_react_composer_container");  
HtmlElement div1 = timelineContainer.FirstChild;

foreach (HtmlElement txtArea in div1.GetElementsByTagName("textarea"))
{
    if(txtArea.GetAttribute("name") == "xhpc_message_text")
    {
        txtArea.SetAttribute("value", "Test V2 \r\n http .. ");
        txtArea.Focus();
    }
}
```

...

```
HtmlElement btn = timelineContainer.GetElementsByTagName("button")[0];
btn.InvokeMember("click");
```